# Does magento backup everything in its installation directory?

Tags: magento2, backup

Magento 2 is installed in public_html folder, all its files directly there.

I want to install wordpress such as `example.com/blog` therefore I placed the blog folder alongside the other folders.

What happens when magento 2 backup all the files, will it include the blog folder too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll hold my hands up and say I haven't tried the default Magento 2 backup/restore method as I don't trust it.  But only because I want to see exactly what is happening.  Which is why I recommend using a shell script you've put together yourself.  But that's for another discussion.

In answer to your question

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/install-gde/install/cli/install-cli-backup.html

> This command enables you to back up:
>
> - The Magento file system (excluding var and pub/static directories)
> - The pub/media directoryThis command enables you to back up:
> - The Magento file system (excluding var and pub/static directories)

So depends on what they mean by Magento file system.  Based on the above info I would say yes - the `/blog` would be covered.  However I wouldn't rely on this until it's too late.  Have you got a test server you can experiment on?

But also did you spot the following note:

> **Deprecation Notice** Magento backup functionality is deprecated as of 2.1.16, 2.2.7, and 2.3.0. We recommend investigating additional backup technologies and binary backup tools (such as Percona XtraBackup).

So depending on what version you are running you might not be covered.

*Update*

Shell script loosely based on this

https://github.com/MagePsycho/magento2-db-code-backup-bash-script

Comment: I did not spot the deprecation notice! I don't want to backup using magento backups anymore! What shell script do you use? The last I want to do is use deprecated tools

Comment: Updated my answer in response to comment

Comment: Thank you so much!